# Drawing Multiple Objects with Python OpenGL and Finding Good Approach

Tags: python, opengl, shader, pyopengl

I'm new to OpenGL and using it with python for a project. I'm trying to draw multiple stuffs just creating a single buffer. I just want to know if it is a good approach, and if not, what am I missing. Also, I want to know if multiple buffers are useful. Also I didn't see any effect of *glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE)* in this code, which was meant to improve visuals. The program shows a little lag when I try to close the window.

I'm just presenting the two functions instead of whole code, just to keep it simple. The *initialize()* function create a shader program and bind a buffer. In *render()* function actual drawing operation takes place. the **vertices** array contains coordinates for circle, and the **triangle** array contains coordinates for triangle. I'm performing three draw operations.

```py
VERTEX_SHADER = """
#version 330
    layout (location = 0) in vec4 position;
    uniform vec4 MVP;

    
    void main() {
    gl_Position = position;
    

}

"""

FRAGMENT_SHADER = """
#version 330
    out vec4 FragColor;
    uniform vec4 ourColor;
    
    
    void main() {

    FragColor = ourColor;

    }

"""

#global varialbles
shaderProgram = None
VBO = None
triangles = []
vertices = []

def initialize():
    global VERTEXT_SHADER
    global FRAGMENT_SHADER
    global shaderProgram
    global triangles
    global vertices 

    #compiling shaders
    vertexshader = shaders.compileShader(VERTEX_SHADER, GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
    fragmentshader = shaders.compileShader(FRAGMENT_SHADER, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)

    #creating shaderProgram
    shaderProgram = shaders.compileProgram(vertexshader, fragmentshader)

    a = 5 
    vertices = []

    for t in np.arange(-4,4,0.01):
        x = a*math.cos(t)
        y = a*math.sin(t)
        
        vertices.append(x)
        vertices.append(y)
        vertices.append(0.0)
 
    vertices = np.array(vertices, dtype=np.float32)
    vertices = vertices/10   
   
    triangles = [-0.5, -0.5, 0.0,
                 0.5, -0.5, 0.0,
                 0.0, 0.5, 0.0]


    triangles = np.array(triangles, dtype=np.float32)

    
    VBO = glGenBuffers(1)
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO)


def render(window):
    global shaderProgram
    global triangles
    global vertices 

    #accessing ourColor variable from shaderProgram
    vertexColorLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "ourColor")

    #####draw figures in screen####
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1)
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

    glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);
    glUseProgram(shaderProgram)


    #draw 1 - circle with fill color
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.nbytes, vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, None)
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
    glUniform4f(vertexColorLoc, 100/255.0, 28/255.0, 20/255.0, 1);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 800)

    #draw 2 - circle border
    glUniform4f(vertexColorLoc, 1, 0, 0, 1);
    glLineWidth(3)
    glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 800)



    #draw 3 - triangle from different vertex array 
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, triangles.nbytes, triangles, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
    glUniform4f(vertexColorLoc, 1, 1, 0, 1);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3)
       
    glUseProgram(0)   

    glfw.swap_buffers(window)
```

[image]

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Actually I wanted to know that the approach I took is good or not. There realized that there are several ways to do the same thing. Which one is more professional?

Comment: It's not a good idea. Uploading data to a buffer is a slow operation and should be avoided. Either create a buffer per object or create a big buffer and put all three objects in. Only upload the data once (unless it changes).

Comment: About the question: You have to focus on a single question. The first paragraph already asks about three different (unrelated) problems. The question about whether something is a good idea is also probably opinion based.

Comment: Thanks @BDL , So I should create a single vertex array for all objects? And, on question, I was confused if this approach is good and if this can be asked here. Should I delete this post?